# Move Linux SSD to another chassis with very same hardware

Tags: linux, ssd, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, compatibility

I have a quite new laptop currently running RHEL7.4 on SSD/luks partition, no kernel customizations.

This machine presented a keyboard problem, so the manufacturer sent me another one - just got it today; the hardware of the received machine is exactly the same as the laptop with jacked keyboard - except obviously for the chassis serial and other unique stuff.

Processor/memory/batteries/PCI, anything exact the same. The HW provider gave me 30 days with the old computer so I can move my data, but turns out that I do not want to go thru the whole setup - I don't have time to, really.

So I want to simply move the SSD from the old laptop to the new one. Considering no HW differences, are there any foreseeable problems with this approach?

Comment: From my understanding, linux loads proper device drives during boot, they are not "installed" per se you can try to simply move the drive and see but I think it should work relatively without a hitch.

Comment: As @Damon says, it should work, but I would boot a Linux Live system to make a copy of the SSD before starting. Then you can be sure of not losing your SSD contents, whatever happens. You can never have too many back-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine for the most part.  There are only 2 places (both unlikely) where I might expect to find issues when moving Linux systems on identical hardware -

1. The IP address of your computer is likely to change, and any portmaps on your router will need to be updated - or your router configuration changed.  This is because the MAC address will be different.   If its just a regular computer running DHCP without running servers, you won't have an issue.   If your IP address is hard coded, the IP address may be associated with a different MAC address and might need updating.
2. Its highly unlikely but if your encryption is using the TPM, this will fail. Most likely you will be able to unlock your drive using an alternative passphrase - and you would then need to work out how to reset the passphrase associated with TPM as the TPM modules will provide different values.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Im sure TPM is not even activated at BIOS, it's luks using GPG encryption.

Comment: my bad, early 'enter'. just a regular computer and, TPM not activated nor tools/module installed loaded. I'll sync BIOS version/configs and attempt the move this affternoon and get back here to close the case.

Comment: Everything goes very smooth. I only had an minor issue with a Symantec AV kernel module, it failed signature verification; simply solve by recompiling it. Appreciate the help.